# How to create dynamic path in website URL using HTML and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need a help for one big problem, i strucked h this problem past two days. the problem is i have developed one website, here users can register and can create separate page for their basic details. and they can give their page to others. its like facebook. eg : **https://www.facebook.com/hanrajas** *facebook* is website and *hanrajas* is name, by using this we can see him page. i need a same option. if i used name after domain name mean im getting **page not found** error.so i need a solution. plz plz help me. i have used PHP, HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, MYSQL to create website.
thank you.

Comment: You should look up information about APIs and how to implement them.  Another option is to use querystring variables so the address would be site.com/page.php?name=hanrajas

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at url rewriting, and mod rewrite

You can create a `.ht_access` file with something like this in it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?user=$1
```

Comment: thank u, but i could not understand clearly. i dont want any ? or = in url. can only use /.